# Server Error in '/' Application. How can fixed to between SQL Server to IIS Connection error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web, iis, server

> Server Error in '/' Application.
> Cannot open database "projectAdelet2" requested by the login. The login failed.
> Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "projectAdelet2" requested by the login. The login failed.
> Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "projectAdelet2" requested by the login. The login failed.
> Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.]
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager) +1524
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +467
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +70
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +940
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +111
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1567
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +118 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +268
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +315 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +128
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +265 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +133 System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +104 System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +503 System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +18 System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +234
> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +321

[EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +741
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions) +167
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +63 System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5() +203 System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +234
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +357
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0() +30 System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +39
System.Linq.Enumerable.LastOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +239 Proview.Controllers.GirisController.Giris(GirisViewModel model) +112 lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +139 System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +280
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +35
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.b__41() +33
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.b__33() +80
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49() +396
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__20() +32
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +187
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +30
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +431
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +75
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +158

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of the below way to resolve this error:

1. Add the iis application pool user in the sql server database
2. Set iis app pool to the custom identity as user which has enough permission to access the sql database:

for that,

- Open iis server, Right click on application pool and select “Advanced Settings”.
- Choose the “Identity” under “Process Model”.
- Choose “Custom Account” and select “Set” to set the account that has access to the SQL Server database.